# How do I remove list of list of list with the same alphabet?

Tags: python, list

I got this list of list of list

```
A=[[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z'], [0, 'w'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']]
```

and in each list of list there are lists with similar alphabets.In this example,it is 'front'.I want to remove the list with similar alphabets,keeping the one with the larger number and removing the one with a smaller number.

Output should be like:

```
A=[[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Z']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z'],[0, 'Z']]
```

Order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get if you want to have apply your process for each list of list separatly or not, but if you do here is one solution:

```
for i, list_dict in enumerate(A):
   uni_dict = {}
   for value, key in list_dict:
      if key in uni_dict:
         uni_dict[key] = max(uni_dict[key], value)
      else:
         uni_dict[key] = value

   A[i] = [[value, key] for key, value in uni_dict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: Yes I have to apply the process for each item separately.But the error say dict object has no attribute iteritems?

Comment: which version of Python are you using?

Comment: I changed it to dict.items but it outputs the same list as the input?

Comment: Check this post to correct your error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops

Comment: I find your desired output with this method, the if should ensure you don't have duplicate keys